# C++ Call by Ref. with a dynamic sized struct without knowing its size

Tags: c++, struct, buffer, pass-by-reference

I need to use a function (part of an API) which stores some requested data into a dynamic sized struct using call by reference. The struct is defined as follows - it concerns access control lists of either posix or NFS4 version, but that is just the use case, I guess.

```
    typedef struct my_struct
    {
      unsigned int len;               /* total length of the struct in bytes */
      ...                             /* some other static sized fields */
      unsigned int version;           /* 2 different versions are possible */
      unsigned int amount;            /* number of entries that follow */
      union {
        entry_v1_t entry_v1[1];
        entry_v2_t entry_v2[1];
      }; 
    } my_struct_t;
```

There are 2 versions of the entries and I know which one I will obtain (v1). Both `entry_v1_t` and `entry_v2_t` are fixed (but different) sized structs just containing integers (so I guess they are not worth being explained here). Now I need to use an existing function to fill my structure with the information I need using Call by Reference, the signature is as follows, including the comments - I don't have access to the implementation:

```
    int get_information(char *pathname, void *ptr);

    /* The ptr parameter must point to a buffer mapped by the my_struct
     * structure. The first four bytes of the buffer must contain its total size.
     */
```

So the point is, that I must allocate memory for that struct but don't know for how much entries (and, as consequence, the total size) I must allocate. Have you ever dealt with such a situation?

Comment: The API expects the caller to allocate the memory, even though the caller doesn't know how much memory to allocate?  That doesn't sound like a great API!

Comment: This pattern is not uncommon in the Windows API, but there is always a mechanism to see how many elements to allocate first...

Comment: Let me check whether there is another opportunity to obtain the number of entries. How should I interpret the entry_v1[ **1** ] ? Is it just a kind of placeholder indicating that there will be a dynamic amount of entries following?

Comment: @David : Yes, exactly; it's a common C-ism.

Comment: @David: `entry_v1[1]` just indicates an array of length 1.  It just so happens to be commonly used as part of the "variable sized struct" trick.

Comment: @ildjarn Yeah reminded me of the Win32 as well - especially reminiscent of those functions that ALSO don't offer any way to find out how much data to allocate. But I agree in general there's a return value or something that tells us how much data to expect. If not, one can try a loop with increasing sizes assuming there's a "too small" error return value. If not even that exists: Seems impossible to handle that situation sensibly.

Comment: If I do not misunderstand, you are laboring under a dangerous misconception. The size of the struct in presented code is constant. The size of a union is the size of the largest member of the union. When you are using the smaller entry type, there will be unused bytes at the end of `my_struct`. (Also, unions need a `};`.)

Comment: @01d55 : You do misunderstand. ;-] The idiom being used here is that described in [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/08/26/220873.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Under Windows API there are many such functions, you normally call them with some NULL pointer to get size of the buffer, then call again with allocated buffer. In case during next call size of buffer have changed function returns error and you need allocate again. So you do it in a while loop till function returns with success.

So your get_information must implement somehow such mechanisms, either it returns false if buffer is to small or returns its correct size if ptr is NULL. But that is just my guess.

Answer (score 0):

OK I thing I figured out how it works. Thanks for your ideas and notes. I declared a `my_struct` pointer and allocated minimum space for the fixed sized fields (5) before the dynamic array  `=> 5 * sizeof(unsigned int)`. Invoking `get_information` with that pointer returns `-1`  and sets `errno = 28` and `strerror(errno) = "No space left on device"`.

But, it sets the `my_struct->len` field to the required size and that seems to be the answer to my question - how should you know? No I can invoke `get_information` initially with the minimum space and figure out how much I need to allocate, and afterwards call it again with the right sized memory allocated to get the information successfully.

The loop solution seems to make sense anyway and would have been my next try - since there are usually just a few entries in that dynamic array.

Thank you.